# Upvoting a post through jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Questions in my application can be upvoted. But, after clicking the upvote button the page reloads. I've searched around and found ways to do it via jQuery so the page does not reload but I am unable to get them to work (I am brand new to jQuery).  Please tell me what I have to add to make this work.

Here is the link to upvote a question:

```
<%= link_to "Upvote", upvote_comment_question_path(question.comment, question) %>
```

And here is the upvote method in the questions controller (right now it redirects back to the same page):

```
 def upvote
   @question = Question.find params[:id]
   @question.liked_by current_user
   redirect_to post_comment_path(@question.comment.post, @question.comment)
 end
```

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really would need jQuery for is updating the upvote count on your page. By convention, links use the GET method but you're modifying something, so PUT is the action you want. You can either modify the method of your link_to or use button_to with a custom action.

Make sure your routes reflect the correct action:

```
resources :questions do
  member do
    put 'update_votes'
  end
end
```

You'll want to start with something like this in your view.

```
<% @questions.each do |q| %>
  <div id="<%= q.id %>">
      <%= link_to "Upvote", upvote_comment_question_path(q.comment, q), remote: true, method: :put %> 
      <div class="upvote-count"><%= q.upvote_count %></div> 
      <div class="question">Content</div><br />
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Your div needs an ID so it can be located at the end when it's updated.

`remote: true` in link_to submits it with AJAX so your page doesn't refresh. At that point, you don't want your upvote action redirecting anywhere, you want it to execute `upvote.js.erb`, which will be its default action anyway. Modify the controller action:

```
 def upvote
   @question = Question.find params[:id]
   @question.liked_by current_user
 end
```

`upvote.js.erb` will have access to @question already, so it just needs to do something like this:

```
$("#<%= @question.id %> .upvote-count").html("<%= @question.likes %>");
```

That should change the value of your upvote count to match the new value.

Comment: First off thanks for the detailed answer! I think i may need to tweak upvote.js.erb for it work though. cached_votes_total where i store the votes so i replaced .upvote-count with that. Do i change @question.likes to question.votes.size (shows the # of votes) though?

Comment: I'm using the acts_as_votable gem btw if you're familiar.

Comment: @user2759575 Just adjust @question.likes to be whatever method you use to display the number of likes on the page, it sounds like that would be `@question.cached_votes_total` if it already has the number saved. `@question.votes.size` would do the same thing but it's a more expensive query, so you should use the cached total if possible.

Comment: Awesome, there we go. Thanks for the help!